# PCLint analyse some files partly

Tags: rhapsody, pc-lint

We are using PCLint to analyse our Rhapsody generated code and would like to ignore errors from the framework code, which is not written by us.

This means that PCLint should analyse some files partly using the annotations generated by Rhapsody. For example, all the three functions below are located in the same source file.

This function is fully auto-generated and should be ignored.

```
static void initStatechart(SomeClass* const me) {
    me->rootState_subState = SomeClass_RiCNonState;
    me->rootState_active = SomeClass_RiCNonState;
}
```

In this function, only the part tagged with "Our code is here" is written by us and should be analysed by PCLint.

```
static void rootState_entDef(void * const void_me) {
    SomeClass * const me = (SomeClass *)void_me;
    {
        me->rootState_subState = SomeClass_InitState;
        me->rootState_active = SomeClass_InitState;
        {
            /*#[ state InitState.(Entry) */

            ..... Our code is here ....

            /*#]*/
        }
        RiCReactive_schedTm(&(me->ric_reactive), 1000, SomeClass_Timeout_InitState_id);
    }
}
```

This function is fully written by us and should be analysed.

```
/*## operation someFunction() */
static void someFunction(SomeClass* const me) {
    /*#[ operation someFunction() */
    .... This function is fully written by us ....
    /*#]*/
}
```

Is it possible ? Maybe using some crazy regex stuff ?

Comment: The options -save and -restore are probably part of the solution. You could e.g. call PC-lint with the option -w0 to initially disable all warnings. You can then put /*lint -save -w3 */ and /*lint -restore */ around your code (or whatever warning level you want to use) to enable warnings for those parts.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried loading the MISRA profile? Rhapsody will then at least generate the statements that PC-Lint uses to ignore violations of MISRA rules.

Walter

Answer (score -1):

The code written by you is easy. You just need to make sure that the file is checked.
PC-Lint warnings in auto-generade functions can be suppressed with 
-esym(#,sym )               suppresses message # for symbol sym
-efunc(#,funcname )      suppresses message # emanating from within function funcname
In your case it would be -efunc( 960, *::initStatechart) to suppress warning 960 for all initStatechart functions in your project.

The difficult part ist the mixed code. There you should work with -save and -restore as already mentioned. You need to find the right properties or insert the command in your code.